# How to access Sharepoint site's document library via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepointadmin

I'm working on accessing document libraries for Sharepoint sites via Mircosoft Graph, but haven't had any luck so far.

Here is my setup:

I have two sites

[https://mydomain.sharepoint.com](https://%3Cmydomain%3E.sharepoint.com)

[https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/teams/MyTestSite](https://%3Cmydomain%3E.sharepoint.com/teams/MyTestSite)

When I make an api call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives, the response doesn't contain id of document library for second site (https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/teams/MyTestSite).

I have gone through documentation and haven't found anything on how to accomplish this. If anyone got any idea about this, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure out a solution for this. A sharepoint site is represented as a Group in Office 365. I found that out by doing some hit and trial.

[image]

So, after looking up their documentation for anything related to a `Group`, I got to this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group

And, by using the [List groups](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list) endpoint I was finally able to get a list of all the Sharepoint sites which the authenticated user can access.

This API call requires `Group.Read.All` scope while requesting access token and only Admin users can authorize this scope. So, this will need a separate interface for Admin to list groups, potentially store the group-user mapping on my app for the user to be able to make api call (/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}) related to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

The V1.0 API has a way to list your doc lib as follows

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/Teams/MyTestSite:/drives
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `beta` API also exposes a [Sharepoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/site) endpoint.

You can also use the path if you already know your site structure:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint:/sites
```